# Running multithreading with tkinter python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am running a tkinter GUI with multithreading. However, the on/off button at the upper right corner of the window is hidden at the time of execution. It appears only when I click on it once. However, when I write threading() function outside the mainloop, it works but shows error " Main thread outside the mainloop" only when I close the GUI
This code is actually a portion of a much larger code in which there are a lot of widgets other than canvas. It takes time to load that GUI. Hence, I thought I should work with threads

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Canvas,Frame,BOTH
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from threading import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self,t):
        self.t=t
    def canvas(self,t):
        canvas = Canvas(t, height = 1080, width= 720)
        canvas.create_line(0, 615,1400,615,width=5)
        canvas.create_line(0,20,1400,20,width=5)
        canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 1400, 20, fill='cornsilk2')
        canvas.create_rectangle(0, 615, 260, 635, fill='cornsilk2')
        canvas.create_rectangle(0, 635, 260, 655, fill='cornsilk2')
        canvas.create_rectangle(0, 655, 260, 675, fill='cornsilk2')
        canvas.create_rectangle(0, 675, 260, 695, fill='cornsilk2')
        canvas.create_rectangle(1100, 615, 1400, 635, fill='cornsilk2')
        canvas.create_rectangle(1100, 635, 1400, 655, fill='cornsilk2')
        canvas.create_rectangle(1100, 655, 1400, 675, fill='cornsilk2')
        canvas.create_rectangle(1100, 675, 1400, 695, fill='cornsilk2')
        canvas.create_oval(1200, 638 , 1210,648, fill="blue")
        canvas.create_oval(1275, 638 , 1285,648, fill="blue")
        canvas.create_oval(1340, 638 , 1350,648, fill="blue")
        lmain = Label(canvas)
        lmain.pack(pady=20)
        canvas.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
m=True
def control(g,t):
    
    global m
      
    # Determin is on or off
    if m:
        h.config(image = off)
        m= False
        
    else:
        h.config(image = on)
        m = True
        
def gui(G,t):
    G.canvas(t)
def threading1():
    t=Thread(target=gui(G,tk))
    t.start()
def threading():
    t3=Thread(target=control(G,tk))
    t3.start()

tk = Tk()
tk.geometry("1080x720")
tk.configure(bg="white")
tk.title("  FIREFIX CONTROL:")
p = PhotoImage(file = 'S:\Ideas\Fire safety Bot\F.png')
tk.iconphoto(False,p)
G=GUI(tk)
threading1()
on=Image.open(r"S:\Ideas\Fire safety Bot\on.png")
on=on.resize((60,25),Image.ANTIALIAS)
on=ImageTk.PhotoImage(on)
off=Image.open(r"S:\Ideas\Fire safety Bot\off.png")
off=off.resize((60,25),Image.ANTIALIAS)
off= ImageTk.PhotoImage(off)
h = Button(tk,bd=0,command=threading,bg="cornsilk2", height =16, width=70)
h.place(relx=0.9,rely=0.03,anchor=SE)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need threading in your case.  BTW `Thread(target=gui(...))` should be `Thread(target=gui, args=(...))` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 I din't understand. Thread(target=gui(G,tk)) is working fine. Also, I will make this GUI much larger hence using thread early on

Comment: shouldn't put gui in a thread, other stuff can be put there but not tkitner

Comment: Do you know the difference between `target=gui(...)` and `target=gui`?  The first one will execute `gui()` immediately in the *main* thread even though `t.start()` is not called.  The later will execute `gui()` in another thread after `t.start()` is executed.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks. But the later one `target=gui` makes the button disapper completely

Comment: It is because the canvas overlaps the button. Also `anchor=SE` will make most of the button out of the window.

Comment: @acw1668 please tell how can I avoid that

Comment: Try 1) add `tk.call("lower", canvas)` at the end of `GUI.canvas()` function;  2) change `Thread(target=gui(G,tk)` to `Thread(target=gui, args=(G,tk))`; 3) change `h.place(..., anchor=SE)` to `h.place(..., anchor=NE)`.